# How to test if none of the iterables are true in Python 3

Tags: python

The task is to take an inputted string (`query`) and see if any of the words match the keys in a dictionary (`rsp_dict`). Simple.

```
words = query.split()

for each in words:
    if each in rsp_dict:
        print(rsp_dict[each])
```

But what I can't figure out, is how to make it print out a phrase if none of the words match keys from the dictionary. I've tried a million different methods, but I always end up with the phrase printing for every False value, rather than just the once.

I'm really hoping to learn from this so any help or guidance is really appreciated. Please also feel free to suggest edits on how I've phrased this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
words = query.split()
not_found = True

for each in words:
    if each in rsp_dict:
        print(rsp_dict[each])
        not_found = False

if not_found:
    print("The phrase was not found!")
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @Tamas Hegedus Thanks for the edit, was a thinking mistake ;)

Comment: Neat, simple solution! Really appreciate the help, thank you! 
I also added a 'break' below the 'not_found = False' for when queries that contained two words matching keys.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming `words = input(*)` here

Using `sets`:

```
not set(words.split()).isdisjoint(rsp_dict.keys())
```

Using `any`:

```
any(w in words.split() for w in rsp_dict.keys())
```

Using a `list comprehension`:

```
[w for w in words.split() if w in rsp_dict.keys()]
```

Using any of these:

```
if (expression):
   print("Found a matching word in phrase")
else:
   print("No matches")
```

Less fancy, but you can always use your regular run of the mill forloop.

Comment: Nice solution, maybe a bit too difficult for beginners!

Comment: Thanks for the help @Pythonista! Taught me a bit about sets - like @linusg mentioned, bit difficult for a beginner like me but always keen to learn.